# Zend/Php/Form - Send variable to an action function

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I searched in internet for information about my problem but I found nothing. I have to send a form to php file. The problem is, I use a framework called zend and I don't understand how to send my variable to an action function from my controller. What can I put in my form action the name of my controller or the name of my function?

My form :

```
<form name=="downloadFile" id="downloadFile" method="POST" action=="ajaxdownloadfile()">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $elem['evt_id']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nomfic" value="<?php $elem['evt_nomfic']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="statut" value="<?php $elem['evt_statut']?>" />
    <img class='js-img-download' type="submit" src='/img/download.png'>
</form>
```

My function action in my controller :

```
public function ajaxdownloadfileAction() {

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        $this->view->lib = $this->_labelsFile;

        $connection = ssh2_connect($this->_configFile->ftp->hostname, $this->_configFile->ftp->port);
        if ($connection) {
            $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->_configFile->ftp->login, $this->_configFile->ftp->password);
            if ($login) {
                $content = true;
                if ($content) { 
                    $id = $this->_getParam('id');
                    var_dump($id);
                    $nomfic = $this->_getParam('nomfic');
                    var_dump($nomfic);
                    $statut = $this->_getParam('statut');
                    echo $statut;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1 ( it is not specified but this code comes from a ZF 1.x application ) there is a standard routing where a controller/action match the www.mydomain.com/{controller}/{action}, for example www.mydomain.com/index/index.

So edit you form action

```
action="/yourcontroller/ajaxdownloadfile"
```

No double "=", no Round brackets.

IF you want to use your controller/action with ajax, just remove the 'action' attribute and create a js function that listen to the submit form event.

There are a lots of tutorial on the web